# Android Q Create and save file

Tags: java, android

I try save a pdf file but on andorid Q I do not see a file. I added all permissions and all permissions are granded also I do this :

```
  public static void saveFile( @NonNull String name, Context context,String base64, Uri imageUri,String path) throws IOException {
        Log.e("Path",path);
        OutputStream fos;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            ContentResolver resolver = context.getContentResolver();
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name + ".pdf");
            contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "application/pdf");
        contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
            fos = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
        } else {
            String imagesDir = path;
            File image = new File(imagesDir, name + ".pdf");
            fos = new FileOutputStream(image);
        }

        byte[] pdfAsBytes = Base64.decode(base64, 0);
        assert fos != null;
        fos.write(pdfAsBytes);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();

    }


FileOutputStream os;
String path;
Uri photoURI = null;
photoURI = getUriForFile(context.getApplicationContext(),
        BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", createImageFile(context,cardId));

File dwldsPath = new File(getDefaultTempFilesPath(context) + "/" + cardId +".pdf");
```

And a probleme is that I do not see a file , a this permissions is added and all is granded :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and I add

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
```

if I do this steal I do not have a file butI do not have any exceptions

```
    private static void createFile(Context ctx, String fileName, String text) {
        File filesDir = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            filesDir = ctx.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
        }
        assert filesDir != null;
        if (!filesDir.exists()){
            if(filesDir.mkdirs()){
            }
        }
        File file = new File(filesDir, fileName + ".txt");
        try {
            if (!file.exists()) {
                if (!file.createNewFile()) {
                    throw new IOException("Cant able to create file");
                }
            }
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(file);
            byte[] data = text.getBytes();
            os.write(data);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
            Log.e("TAG", "File Path= " + file.toString());
            if(file.exists()){
                Log.e("d","d");
            }
            File fileTemp = new File(file.getPath());
            FileInputStream notes_xml = new FileInputStream(fileTemp);
            byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)notes_xml.available()];
//The information will be content on the buffer.

            notes_xml.read(fileContent);

            String strContent = new String(fileContent);
            Log.e("content",strContent);
            notes_xml.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: do you have any exceptions? have you double checked the file location?

Comment: @MartinFrank I do not have an exceptions a file is not created

Comment: I have an exception java.io.IOException: No such file or directory

Comment: have you checked if that directory exists - the directory where you want to store the file?

Comment: @MartinFrank yes I am

Comment: so the **directory exists** and the **file name** does **not contain any path-elements**?

Comment: @MartinFrank I edit my post

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205912/discussion-between-kiki-kala2-and-martin-frank).

Comment: @MartinFrank I do not have an exceptions

Comment: Likely you don't need `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"`, but a [`FileProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider). I'm also rather certain it's a duplicate question, am just too lazy to search now.

Comment: @MartinZeitler I have a FileProvider

Comment: `And a probleme is that I do not see a file`. You did not tell how you tried to find the file. Using a file manager? Please be exact.

Comment: `on andorid Q I do not see a file. I added all permissions and all permissions are granded also I do this :`. On Q you di not need any permission writing to the media store.

Comment: @blackapps in file manager I do not see this file

Comment: @blackapps how I can save file in andorid Q ?

Comment: It is unclear why you also posted code to create files. What has it to do with your first code that saved to the media store,?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205917/discussion-between-kiki-kala2-and-blackapps).

Comment: As you posted the code in reversed order i now see that you do not use getContenrResolver().insert() to obtain an uri from the media store. That uri you could use then to open that output stream. Throw away the rest of the code.

Comment: @blackapps so what I should to do ?

Comment: @blackapps how this insert you look like ?

Comment: @blackapps             url=   resolver.insert(MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),contentValues);
 this ?

Comment: https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/12/21/scoped-storage-stories-storing-mediastore.html